# Android: Picasso Callback is not calling initial time

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, picasso

I am using Picasso library in Marker **getInfoWindow()** function, for loading image in the marker info window.

Here in the Picasso **callBack** **onSuccess** function I tried to refresh the the info window by using the function   **marker.showInfoWindow()** , for loading the image in info window.

But when I click the marker , Info window will open, but the Picasso Callback OnSuccess is not calling initially.

When I click the marker agian, the OnSuccess function will call.

```
ImageView imgDeal = (ImageView) infowindow.findViewById(R.id.image_view_icon);

Picasso.with(infowindow.getContext())
.load(mURL)
.into(imgDeal, new Callback() {
@Override
 public void onSuccess() {
  Log.e("Tag ", "Picasso onSuccess" );
  marker.showInfoWindow();
 }

@Override
 public void onError() {
  Log.e("Tag ", "Picasso onError" );
 }
});
```